# Class weights for multi-output classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have a problem where i created a model like this :

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense,  Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import LSTM, Conv1D, Input, MaxPooling1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

posts_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='posts')
embedded_posts = Embedding(max_nb_words, embedding_vector_length, input_length=max_post_len)(posts_input)

x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_posts)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
x = Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
x = Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

Axe1_prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='axe1')(x)
Axe2_prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='axe2')(x)
Axe3_prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='axe3')(x)
Axe4_prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='axe4')(x)

model = Model(posts_input, [Axe1_prediction, Axe2_prediction, Axe3_prediction, Axe4_prediction])
```

as you can see, this model has 4 outputs.

Then i compile this model like this :

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
              loss=['binary_crossentropy', 
                    'binary_crossentropy', 
                    'binary_crossentropy', 
                    'binary_crossentropy'],
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

For fitting this model, i think i need to set the class weights, so i create these :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

le = LabelEncoder()
y1 = le.fit_transform(df2["Axe1"])
y2 = le.fit_transform(df2["Axe2"])
y3 = le.fit_transform(df2["Axe3"])
y4 = le.fit_transform(df2["Axe4"])

cw1 = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y1), y1)
cw2 = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y2), y2)
cw3 = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y3), y3)
cw4 = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y4), y4)
```

But finally i don't know how to set this parameters in the fitting :

```
history = model.fit(X_train, 
          [y1_train, y2_train, y3_train, y4_train], 
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(X_val, [y1_val, y2_val, y3_val, y4_val]));
```

Could you help me by showing how i can add the "class_weights =" parameter ?

Comment: instead of multiple outputs in your model, i believe you can use a dense layer with 4 outputs, and apply the sigmoid activation to that. then use binary cross-entropy as usual.

Comment: yeah i know but the idea of using this type of model is a contraint of the project

Answer (score 1):

You have to use tensorflow 2.1 or earlier. The class weights fuctionality has beed removed after TF2.1 for multioutput models

Answer (score 1):

If you want still to use tensorflow > 2.1, you need to define a custom loss instead, something similar as below :

```
from functools import partial
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(target, output, weights_table):
    # get the given weight
    weights_vect = weights_table.lookup(target)
    return K.binary_crossentropy(target, output) * weights_vect

# transform dictionary of weights into lookup table that can be used
def to_lookup_table(dictionary):
    return tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
        tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
            list(dictionary.keys()), #[0,1]
            list(dictionary.values()), # corresponding weights
            key_dtype=tf.int64,
            value_dtype=tf.float32,
        ),
        default_value=-1)

cw1 = ...
cw2 = ...
cw3 = ...
cw4 = ...

# define function where weights_table already defined
binary_crossentropy_1 = partial(weighted_binary_crossentropy, weights_table=to_lookup_table(cw1))
...
binary_crossentropy_4 = partial(weighted_binary_crossentropy, weights_table=to_lookup_table(cw4))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
              loss=[binary_crossentropy_1, ..., binary_crossentropy_4],
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Depending on how you define the weights dictionary and the output of your model, you might have to change the type of the `target`, its shape, or removing the `argmax`. You might also to change the type of the keys and values in the `to_lookup_table` function.

For those who need a categorical crossentropy at the end, just replace `K.binary_crossentropy` by `K.categorical_crossentropy`.